# I want to show navigation arrows in luma theme

Tags: magento2, frontend, menu, topmenu, less-css

I want to show navigation arrows in **luma theme** like **blank theme nav** of Magento 2.

Anybody can suggest me how can I do this ?

Comment: Where you want to show arrow can't see in blank theme

Comment: I am using luma theme and by default navigation icons not coming in luma theme, can you suggest me how to do this.

Comment: In desktop view you can't see icons but in mobile you can see luma and blank both themes

Comment: yes but I want to enable them on desktop as well,  how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override below css in your theme :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/_navigation.less

Removed below css from Line no. 52 to 79

```
.navigation {
    padding: 0;

    .parent {
        .level-top {
            position: relative;
            .lib-icon-font(
            @_icon-font-content: @icon-down,
            @_icon-font-size: 42px,
            @_icon-font-position: after,
            @_icon-font-display: block
            );

            &:after {
                position: absolute;
                right: 7px;
                top: -8px;
            }

            &.ui-state-active {
                .lib-icon-font-symbol(
                @_icon-font-content: @icon-up,
                @_icon-font-position: after
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Add Line no. 45

```
.navigation {
    padding: 0;

    .parent {
        .level-top {
            position: relative;
            .lib-icon-font(
            @_icon-font-content: @icon-down,
            @_icon-font-size: 42px,
            @_icon-font-position: after,
            @_icon-font-display: block
            );

            &:after {
                position: absolute;
                right: 7px;
                top: -8px;
            }

            &.ui-state-active {
                .lib-icon-font-symbol(
                @_icon-font-content: @icon-up,
                @_icon-font-position: after
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> adjust font-size as and position as per your theme requirements.